# Parser for tab-delimited data as a subclass of StringReader

Tags: c#, object-oriented, parsing, csv

I wanted to parse lines of text as tab-delimited items, and I had just been using a StringReader for something else and I came up with this:

```
class TabDelimitedFieldReader : StringReader
    {
        private string _nextLine;
        public TabDelimitedFieldReader(string s)
            : base(s)
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<string> ReadFields()
        {
            if (_nextLine != null)
            {
                var fields = _nextLine.Split('\t');
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    yield return field;
                }
            }
        }

        public bool HasMore
        {
            get
            {
                _nextLine = this.ReadLine();
                return (_nextLine != null);
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't think of another time I directly subclasses a .NET framework class like this.  I figure maybe I'm just strange and it's normal for others, or maybe there's a reason I wouldn't want to do it.

Comment: Not a bad idea. How do you use it, however? Say, I wanted to get text out of clipboard which got pasted in Excel. Then, I would want to make sure that row length is consistent - something that an enumerator would not give me. I would also add an optional bool flag to the `ReadFields` function which would cause the fields to be trimmed if `true`. I would run StyleCop on this, which would force you to add comments and rename `_nextLine` to `nextLine`, and refer to it as `this.nextLine`, etc.

Comment: The context was an ad-hoc report loader service that aggregated data from a list of databases, which I copied/pasted from excel data formatted as a table, so even blanks will generate a blank field, and rows all the same length.  Really, style cop would make me use "this" everywhere?  I just changed my ambition to work at MS :)

Comment: You can turn off the rules that you do not agree with.

Comment: actually i decided to code the rest of the day using no underscores and "this", and I realized it has a sort of leveling effect that lets me move code in/out/around namespaces/classes/nested classes more freely, so I think I'll stick with it

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, I do not see anything inherently wrong with subclassing a framework object, particularly since many of them provide `virtual`/`abstract` members specifically to allow it.

In this case, it may be better to wrap a `TextReader` object instead of inheriting from `StringReader`.  This would allow you to provide tab delimited reading for multiple data sources instead of limiting yourself to in-memory strings.  For example, you could still pass in a `StringReader` for reading strings, but you could also pass in a `StreamReader` if you wanted to support reading from files instead.

Additionally, I noticed that `HasMore` is dangerous to call due to its side-effect.  It is not immediately obvious to a caller that checking `HasMore` would alter the reader's current position.  I would suggest using `Peek` instead.

You would then need to update `_nextLine` elsewhere.  You could have it be a side-effect of calling `ReadFields`.  Or, perhaps better, you could add another method (e.g., `AdvanceLine`) that is simply responsible for moving the reader to the next line.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - question: are you a TDD developer? I'm not but have been lightly using/learning it for a while, and from my limited understanding, code that works is the goal and pre-empting the future is frowned upon... which goes against my instincts too, but seems to be the primary directive (as I understand it).

Comment: By wrapping the class, you are actually reducing the test surface area, as you only need test your externally visible (public/protected) members.  By extending StringReader, you would be stuck testing for cases where callers use the public base class methods to ensure you properly handle side-effects.  For example, if someone called ReadLine (from TextReader), it would skip a line, changing expected behavior for either ReadFields or HasMore (or both!).

Comment: @AaronAnodide it's called the decorator pattern. All stream in .NET work in this way. For example you can create a `MemoryStream` from a `FileStream`.